# Problema no select

Tags: mysql

Como resolver isso?

```
create table tbl_prescricao(
id_prescricao int not null primary key auto_increment,
tipo_prescricao varchar(250) not null,
valor_prescricao decimal(10,2)
);

create table tbl_juntaprescricao(
id_junta int not null primary key auto_increment,
prescricao int not null,
constraint fk_prescricao foreign key (prescricao) references tbl_prescricao 
(id_prescricao),
prescricao2 int,
constraint fk_prescricao2 foreign key (prescricao2) references 
tbl_prescricao (id_prescricao)
);

insert into tbl_prescricao values
(1, 'Remédio 1', 59.00),
(2, 'Remédio 2', 80.00),
(3, 'Remédio 3', null);

insert into tbl_juntaprescricao values (1, 1, 2), (2, 3, null);

select tipo_prescricao from tbl_juntaprescricao as J
inner join tbl_prescricao as P on J.prescricao = P.id_prescricao
inner join tbl_prescricao as P on J.prescricao2 = P.id_prescricao;
```

Ao fazer o select ocorre o erro: Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/alias: 'P'

Preciso que ele traga o nome dos remédios na tabela tbl_juntaprescricao.

Se não fui específico com o problema me pergunte mais detalhes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O alias tem que ser único. Nas últimas linhas faça a seguinte alteração:

```
select P.tipo_prescricao, P2.tipo_prescricao from tbl_juntaprescricao as J
inner join tbl_prescricao as P on J.prescricao = P.id_prescricao
inner join tbl_prescricao as P2 on J.prescricao2 = P2.id_prescricao;
```